# Get string between tag from a string

Tags: java, android, regex, string, vcf-vcard

I'm not very familiar with Regex so I'm asking it here.

I've a string like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:A Sirius Swimwear Collection
N:Collection;A;Sirius Swimwear;;
TEL;TYPE=HOME:22448
TEL;TYPE=CELL:52316
ADR:;Taylors Road;;;;;
ORG:Norfolk Phone Book
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:A Walk in the Wild
N:Wild;A;Walk in the;;
TEL;TYPE=HOME:22502
item1.TEL:23205
item1.X-ABLabel:Facsimile
ADR:;Grassy Road;;;;;
ORG:Norfolk Phone Book
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:AATA Orn Tours
N:Tours;AATA;Orn;;
TEL;TYPE=HOME:23611
TEL;TYPE=CELL:50755
ADR:;Bookings;;;;;
ORG:Norfolk Phone Book
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Aatuti Art
N:Art;Aatuti;;;
TEL;TYPE=HOME:23669
ADR:;The Village;;;;;
ORG:Norfolk Phone Book
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:ABC Hobby Centre
N:Centre;ABC;Hobby;;
TEL;TYPE=HOME:22139
ADR:;Taylors Road;;;;;
ORG:Norfolk Phone Book
END:VCARD
(...)
```

For those familiar with, it is a bunch of VCards and I want to get a VCard one by one from the String. So, I want to split it up in multiple Strings. I want to split with the `BEGIN:VCARD` and `END:VCARD` tags

End up with:

```
vcard1 = "BEGIN:VCARD
    VERSION:3.0
    FN:A Sirius Swimwear Collection
    N:Collection;A;Sirius Swimwear;;
    TEL;TYPE=HOME:22448
    TEL;TYPE=CELL:52316
    ADR:;Taylors Road;;;;;
    ORG:Norfolk Phone Book
    END:VCARD";

vcard2 = "BEGIN:VCARD
    VERSION:3.0
    FN:A Walk in the Wild
    N:Wild;A;Walk in the;;
    TEL;TYPE=HOME:22502
    item1.TEL:23205
    item1.X-ABLabel:Facsimile
    ADR:;Grassy Road;;;;;
    ORG:Norfolk Phone Book
    END:VCARD";

vcard3 = "BEGIN:VCARD
    VERSION:3.0
    FN:AATA Orn Tours
    N:Tours;AATA;Orn;;
    TEL;TYPE=HOME:23611
    TEL;TYPE=CELL:50755
    ADR:;Bookings;;;;;
    ORG:Norfolk Phone Book
    END:VCARD";
```

Honestly, I just need the right regex pattern as the cycles I'm able to do them.
This is in JAVA (For Android).

**EDIT**

This is what I've tried so far to no success:

```
if(vcard.contains("VERSION:"))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating the patterns");
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("BEGIN:VCARD(.*)END:VCARD");

            Matcher m = p.matcher(vcard);

            if (m.find()) 
            {

                Log.d(TAG, "Find: " + m.group(1));

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Not found anything");
```

Comment: Nice, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think you need a regex here, just start building a string when you find a `BEGIN:VCARD` line and add the built string to a list when you find a `END:VCARD` line.

Comment: You could have added the code sample you tried earlier to avoid that.

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc humm, didn't thought it that way. It makes sense. I'm going to try that approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Pattern.DOTALL` with your regex. It means `In dotall mode, the expression dot(.) matches any character, including a line terminator` and it will help you to match pattern from multiple lines.

```
String input = "__YOUR__VCARDS__";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(BEGIN:VCARD.*?END:VCARD)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Damn, I was so close :) Just missing the `Pattern.DOTALL`. Thanks, it's working!

Answer (score 0):

You should try [ez-vcard](http://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/).  It's a Java vCard library that works on Android.

Disclaimer: I am the author ;)